# What is Bootstrapping in statistics? How can I use it to determine error in the mean, variance, kurtosis and skewness of a data set?

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

From what I understood from searching randomly is that it has something to do with resampling. What does this resampling mean? Is it selecting random data from a distribution or is it getting data from somewhere else?

Comment: you might want to post this instead on the statistics stack exchange.  Briefly, you treat the sample data as the population and sample with replacement using your new sample to calculate the confidence interval of some statistic in order to determine the robustness of your estimate of said statistic.

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/